# android : "video recording finished" notification

Tags: android, android-camera, android-broadcast

I'm working on a project which need to trigger some action just after the camera finishes recording a video and store it in sdcard. I could find broadcasts that tells us when a photo is captured by the camera and stored in sdcard. I could also find a broadcast "`android.hardware.action.NEW_VIDEO`" which is available from API level 14 or above. That helps us detecting the newly recorded video. How can we implement the same in the API levels 8 to 14..?? My searches didn't bring me a proper solution. Hope someone could help me out here. :)

Thanks in advance.